# Compassion's Unity

Tags: compassion, metta, metta-bhavana

My question is two-fold.

First, I believe that *metta* is classified as a meditation object involving concentration. Yet, in [this](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.01083/full) study, researchers suggest it is a mixture of focused attention (e.g. *shamatha*) and open monitoring (e.g. *vipassana*). **Does Buddhism suggest in certain passages or teachings that compassion is dual in this way?**

More so, from my experience, compassion meditations deepens insight. Theravada involves a mixture of *shamatha* and *vipassana*, and the Mahayana involves (more so) a union of compassion and wisdom recognizing *sunyata*. I feel the depth of *metta* might occur from its union of concentration and insight (as suggested in the previous paragraph) and from *metta* itself and the realization of *sunyata* (implied by their merging promoted by the Mahayana). I feel all these things occur with *metta* in my experience.

When talking about *metta* a researcher described the occurrence of gamma waves:

> [Davidson found their brainwaves showed never-before-seen levels of gamma, one of the strongest types of brain waves,  theorized to appear when the different regions of the brain harmonize.](https://www.mindful.org/the-remarkable-brains-of-high-level-meditators/)

**In Buddhism teachings and texts, is metta said to unite a variety of mental factors together?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are always a perfect subject for training metta, Eggman, yet it wouldn't unite other then wisdom very individual, if. In the case Eggman is giving other such possibilities consciously he might even gain some merits by it.

Maybe Eggman likes to perceive hungry small beings running around bind in search for food and even if given are not capable to grasp. When certain sense of samvega, reflecting ones own situation, comes along with it, you possible got the right "wave", possible gain even a first taste of food.

*(note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks or entertaining by joint-adventures but to escape from that very wheel)*